# Datatables pagination buttons - Remove unwanted space

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, datatables

Currently my pagination looks as such:
[image]

I'm trying to work out how to remove the space between the buttons, but have been unsuccessful. In the css files the only references I can find to pagination are:

jquery.dataTables.css (319 - 394):

```
}
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 0.25em;
}
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 1.5em;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  margin-left: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  *cursor: hand;
  color: #333333 !important;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current:hover {
  color: #333333 !important;
  background-color: white;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, white), color-stop(100%, gainsboro));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, gainsboro 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, gainsboro 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, gainsboro 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, gainsboro 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 0%, gainsboro 100%);
  /* W3C */
}
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled:hover, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled:active {
  cursor: default;
  color: #666 !important;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
}
/*.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button:hover {
  color: white !important;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: white;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #585858), color-stop(100%, #111111));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #585858 0%, #111111 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #585858 0%, #111111 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #585858 0%, #111111 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #585858 0%, #111111 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #585858 0%, #111111 100%);
  /* W3C */
} */
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button:active {
  outline: none;
  background-color: #2b2b2b;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #2b2b2b), color-stop(100%, #0c0c0c));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2b2b2b 0%, #0c0c0c 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2b2b2b 0%, #0c0c0c 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2b2b2b 0%, #0c0c0c 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2b2b2b 0%, #0c0c0c 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2b2b2b 0%, #0c0c0c 100%);
  /* W3C */
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #111;
}
```

dataTables.bootstrap.css (32 - 50):

```
div.dataTables_paginate {
    margin: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: right;
}

div.dataTables_paginate ul.pagination {
    margin: 2px 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    div.dataTables_length,
    div.dataTables_filter,
    div.dataTables_info,
    div.dataTables_paginate {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

However, I can't seem to find a reference to any large margins or padding. Although CSS isn't exactly my strong suit.

Does anyone know if there are other references to the paginate buttons that might be related? Or have to fix the problem outright?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This issue has already been noted in their bug database.
You do not need to hack the css.

[bootstrap pagination looks bad #39](https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/issues/39#issuecomment-35016269)

> No need to include DataTables' own stylesheet (jquery.dataTables.css) since Bootstrap and the integration file provide everything that is needed.

So just delete `jquery.dataTables.css`, and keep `dataTables.bootstrap.min.css` in your html style sheets.

Comment: I love down votes without comments to indicate why. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this, it also fixed an issue where there were boxes appearing above the order arrows in each column - very weird (I was also using the Japanese language file, not sure if it made a different) hope this could help others out there too.

Comment: You saved my day, after struggling much trying to manually do it in my css, this solution worked perfectly

Comment: Thank you for your intelligence. You should be hired by the teams who wrote their documentation...

Comment: @karns their software should prevent you from making this mistake.

Answer (score 18):

Oh yes. Easy to reproduce the error. To solve it, add this CSS after other CSS references :

```css
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button {
    padding : 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    display: inline;
    border: 0px;
}
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button:hover {
    border: 0px;
}
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/s6c35ogt/**
Try to comment out the added CSS in the top right corner, and you will see the exact same behaviour as you describe.

Comment: Could kiss you :p

Answer (score 1):

`.paginate_button { padding: 0!important; margin-left: 0!important; }`
For not a single space

Answer (score 0):

As Bae pointed out, including 'jquery.dataTables.css' does cause this bug.

But, if you are using the DataTables' 'select' functionality, the visual aspects will be lost by removing this .css file.

So, it really is a decision you make of removing the .css file if you do not use 'select', if you do, you'll have to pinch the css styling for selected items.
Or, keep the .css and overwrite the css so that the pagination is not messy.
This CSS will remove all of the messy spacing around pagination.

```
.dataTables_paginate ul li {
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    border: 0px !important;
}
```