# How to remove spaces in the Datatables pagination buttons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, bootstrap-4

Can you please help me to find a way to remove the spaces in the datatables pagination buttons?

[image]

I've referred the below URL's for doing so :

[DATA TABLES BOOTSTRAP 4 EXAMPLE](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4)

I've added the .js and CSS files exactly as it was said in above, but it did't work.

[Datatables pagination buttons - Remove unwanted space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28955336/datatables-pagination-buttons-remove-unwanted-space)

None of the above are working. Kindly help me to override the current functionality. Thank you.

Please find the code I've worked below :

### HTML

```
  <!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="javascript/third_party/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="javascript/third_party/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <!-- DATA TABLES -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>
```

### CSS

```
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button {
  padding : 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  display: inline;
  border: 0px;
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button:hover {
  border: 0px;
}
```

### Jquery

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment('MM/DD/YYYY');
  $(`#${ID}`).DataTable({
    columnDefs: [{
      targets: [0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7],
      orderable: false
    }],
    "order": [[4, "asc"]]
  });
```

Comment: add some code to your question so that we will be able to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Datatables pagination buttons - Remove unwanted space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28955336/datatables-pagination-buttons-remove-unwanted-space)

Comment: @yash...I've added the code. Please check. Also please remove the tag as duplicate as- It wasn't working. The same URL was even mentioned in the question. Thank you.

Comment: i'm not able to even run that solution. do you have [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) link ?

Comment: did you tried [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4) with same js and css link?

Comment: @yash, Yes I've tried with the exact same js and CSS CDN mentioned.

Comment: Hi @METALHEAD, i tried the same example in [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/zakowoxexe/edit?html,js,output) and it is working fine. try to comment other css temporary to see, are they creating problems or what?

Comment: i have updated answer. Hope this may work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After so many research, I found out that

while using bootstrap css, do not use `jquery.dataTables.css` with it. else it will create spacing issue in pagination.

Bootstrap Datatable 4 independently works good as you see in [JsBin](http://DATA%20TABLES%20BOOTSTRAP%204%20EXAMPLE) that i created.

Hope, if you point correct URL of **poper.js** which is as following :
else this will also create issue with bootstrap 4 css.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**EDIT :** 
If you see below [codepen](https://codepen.io/yash-soni/pen/xaYbZP), which has same issue that your are facing.

if you open that codepen, and remove the following line and it's work fine for you.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10-dev/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
```

Hope this may work for you. if not, comment down below.

Comment: Yes..Guess there is something wrong with my code. The JsBin code that you attached is independently working fine. I need to check what has wrong with my existing code. Thank you so much for your time in guiding me through this.

Comment: @METALHEAD, are you using both css ? bootstrap and jquery datatable?

Comment: Yes I am using both yash

Comment: @METALHEAD, that's the issue. remove jquery datatable css. and problem solved.

Comment: Adding to your answer - One more mistake I've done is : in the .CSS, I've styled `li` for the `navigation bar`. That has actually messed up with the pagination. Ur `JSbin` code is my life saver... \m/. Happy coding..!!!!

Comment: This didn't apply to the issue for me. I had the same spacing issue, but it turned out to be the margin on <li class="paginate_button page-item "> getting overwritten by my Wordpress theme. li {
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    margin-left: 15px; change this to 0 and spaces went away
    margin-right: 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

As Yash pointed out, including 'jquery.dataTables.css' does cause this bug.

But, if you are using the DataTables' 'select' functionality, the visual aspects will be lost by removing this .css file.

So, it really is a decision you make of removing the .css file if you do not use 'select', if you do, you'll have to pinch the css styling for selected items.
Or, keep the .css and overwrite the css so that the pagination is not messy.
This CSS will remove all of the messy spacing around pagination.

```
.dataTables_paginate ul li {
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    border: 0px !important;
}
```